# load styles after component load in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Can I Load custom styles like

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})
```

in component load ??
Because I have multiple fontFamily name in multiple language.

now, My styles load before component load

Comment: theywill load before , but if you want to switch the styles you can always do that right?

Comment: yes, I can switch between styles but I want to find a way to load styles in component load because I use i18n for language switch and need switch between 2 font for Arabic number digit and English number digit